# Global environment variables for AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to have global environment variables in a AWS CloudFormation yaml file for Lambdas?

Currently we are using the SSM Parameter Store for global variables, but we don't want to use that anymore.

I looking forward to have something like this:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    variable1: xxx // local variables
    variable2: xxx
    ...
  ${file(./globalvariables.yml)} // global variables
```

Or even better: every lambda is including the global environment variables as default without explicitly calling it.

Is this possible? Or what approach would you suggest? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you expand on why don't you want to use SSM Parameter Store? Personally I think SSM Parameter Store is a good choice as it's centralised, easily modified, supports IAM and can be encrypted.

Comment: The reason for that is the very slow SSM Parameter Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I'm unaware of having predefined defaults for environment variables to be set through CloudFormation for Lambdas however - One possible option is instead of using env variables in CloudFormation add a lambda layer with all the config and pull the values from there.

Benefits of this are that if a value changes you only have to update your layer once then update lambdas to use new layer which could be a single parameter instead of manually updating every single one.

Docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Another option would be to use AWS Secrets Manager Or SSM Parameter Store as ServerMonkey suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I think layers is the way to go